# How to reflect multiple cells based on specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Imagine a list on the left filled with employees going down the spreadsheet and headers across the top based categorized on infractions that an employee might violate.  this sheet is connected to another sheet which adds a one every time a form is submitted against the employee adding up for the quarter.  So employee john smith has across his row would show a 0 if he never committed this infraction and add a 1 to the column each time he did so a row might look like this.  John Smith 0  4  5  0  1

The goal is to show the experts name and infraction with how many times this infraction took place removing the infractions that he did not commit so ideally it would look like John Smith 4 5 1 and the header of each number would show what he did.

The goal is to make it much easier to see who did what essentially. There will be over 100 employees and alot of 0's so optically it would look better to distill in order to quickly identify who did what and how many times.

Any ideas?

V lookups and important ranges based on if this is greater than 0 is tedious and does not exactly pull what we want. Essentially omitting the 0s and just showing what an employee has done rather than what they have not done is the goal.  All index and match formulas do not seem to specifically answer this problem

simple Index V lookups and matching formulas have been tried

Not able to reflect all three variables (employee/frequency/infraction) while not showing on a master list the people who did not commit the offense

Comment: Where do you want to show this information?  Only one person at a time, and how would you pick who to display?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you could set this up. I would set this up so it

Column A = Employee

Column B = Infraction

Column C = 1

Column D = Date

That way you can do a pivot summary and have the employees, with their infractions below their name and the months/years they occurred. Also you can adjust this table as necessary, such as filter by the employee name or by date or by infraction.

The added benefit is you could create a chart with all of these as filters, like cutoff a date range or pick an employee or infraction and it can show a bar graph of all the infractions by month or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response Mark! How would that work for example if there was 20+ separate infractions? and how could we omit employees who did not have any record as they are not needed in the assessment ?  Currently I have column A all the employees going down and B-Z columns as possible infractions going across with 0,1,2 ect going across each  employee row showing  its count.  Date is not as crucial as these are quarterly reviews.

Comment: you can see with that model 100+ employees with 20+ infractions how verbose it might be which is why infractions are laid across the top and count going across as rows am I missing something on how this would make the sheet more concise and optically pleasing?

Comment: So you would have a tab dedicated to the raw information. 100 * 20 = 2,000, but excel can support 1 million rows. So when it's summarized on the pivot table that's where it's optically pleasing and the analysis can take place. If an employee doesn't receive any infractions, they would be omitted from the dataset or you can have a 'No infraction' under the infraction type or a 0 under the value.

Comment: I am hoping to show all offenders at once on one spreadsheet going across showing employee infraction and frequency I understand how to visualize this pivot/dash but this is a sheet that would have 100 + employees going down infractions going across and count coming from another sheet thats automated. I was thinking distilling the main sheet down by an IF INDEX match formula if infractions are greater than 0 index original data set and return infractions and employee where this is true essential a filter but for rows and columns anything come to mind on how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that listing your data of infractions line by line (as they happen) and using a pivot table would probably be the easiest.

You could also use the AGGREGATE function to pull from a large database as well.  This way you could type in an employees name, and a list of all infractions would pop up next to the name (or wherever you would want it) with as much detail as you would like.  This way is more complex, but using both a pivot table and the AGGREGATE function might get you the best of both worlds (you could searching infraction types, dates, employees, employee types, and get all the details in the world if wanted).

Hope this helps!

JW

Comment: I appreciate all of the suggestions thank you both! Ideally there would be a way to look at a master list without pivot tables and data validation drop downs as those have been ruled out.  I was looking more for a set/forumula on another sheet with the main data set showing everything  that would distill the list to show only employees who had an infraction frequency of each and the corresponding infraction

Comment: Im thinking a combination of IF greater then 1 INDEX whole sheet that and match 2 cells (infraction and employee) any formulas come to mind? If INDEX MATCH formulas

Comment: is the object have a worksheet that shows all "offenders" at once? Or to be able to lookup a name and see a list of the infractions they have?  Maybe making a dashboard with a pivot table to show the former and using AGGREGATE to show the later might serve you well.

Comment: Yes show all offenders at once what was the infraction and frequency we are trying to avoid searching by person as many managers have multiple members of the team and do not want to look up each person specifically I know how to do a pivot / dashboard to get these results but im looking more for if employee has infraction greater than 0 show employee infraction and frequency for 100+ people on one spreadsheet

Comment: You could use a COUNTIF function to get a total number of infractions for each employee.  Then from that us an IF statement to check if that number is at least 1, then INDEX, AGGREGATE to pull from the master data page for each cell of the first infraction.  Then in the second row do the same thing if the number is at least 2, and so on.  But this would test for each employee, so you would first want to create a list of employees that have an infraction.  Could use the IF statement you suggested.  Somewhat complex, but with some effort you could make it dynamic.